# Kernel Development on windows platform

Tags: linux-kernel, cygwin

I have installed windows 10 on my system.I have also installed cygwin on my system.I want to start learning kernel development.Is there any way to install, make and build kernel using cygwin on windows platform?If not,then I want to know any other way to do the same.I don't want to use a virtual machine.

Comment: I have tried installing virtual machine and running ubuntu on it.But,it makes my system slow.Dual booting is also making my system slow.

Comment: Hmm. An OS should have the same performance whether it was started on a dedicated machine or one configured for dual-boot.

Comment: Learning linux kernel development is a long and complicated task. Why making it harder ? Just install a Linux distro and you're done.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin has nothing to do with *nix kernel. It's basically two things: a Windows DLL that implements some of the POSIX API and shells and tools that run against it. Together these provide a Unix "look and feel" on Windows. (There is a port of gcc and other parts of the GNU build chain but these just produce more native binaries that can use the DLL.)

Use a VM. Or you could look into something called [Cooperative Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_Linux). I don't have any experience with it myself but the [home page](http://www.colinux.org/) says it is a...

> ...free and open source method for optimally running Linux on
>   Microsoft Windows natively...a port of the Linux kernel that allows it
>   to run cooperatively alongside another operating system on a single
>   machine....run Linux on Windows 2000/XP/Vista/7, without using a
>   commercial PC virtualization software such as VMware

I only mention it in case you absolutely can't run a traditional VM for some reason.

Comment: Yes, a virtual machine on Windows would definitely be the best approach.